# Closing OleDbConnection slow

Tags: vb.net

I am using this function to upload a excel file in a datatable or datagridview, my problem is that at the beginning the program was executed instantaneously but now wastes a couple of seconds running the command xlsConn.Close (), any idea why now is slower if at the beginning it ran instantly? Also if I eliminate that command (xlsConn.Close ()), I will have any problems? I've seen that I get some problems trying to open the uploaded excel file, it only gives me reading access.

```
    Function ReadExcelFile(ByVal InputFile As String, ByVal DataSheet As String)

    InputFile = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & InputFile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
    DataSheet = "select * from [" & DataSheet & "$]"

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim xlsConn As OleDbConnection
    xlsConn = New OleDbConnection(InputFile)

    Try
        xlsConn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = xlsConn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = (DataSheet)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

    Catch
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        xlsConn.Close()
        xlsConn = Nothing
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Did you make any change to the code in the meanwhile?

Comment: No, is the same. At the beginning the program made a calculation in 2 seconds and now for the same calculation takes 24 seconds

Comment: I've tested the program in another pc and the program runs correctly. I don't understand it. Can be that my computer is corrupted, damaged,  or something like that?